# git, работа в команде

Tags: git

если у нас команда из нескольких человек(до 10-ти), то как лучше организовать ветки (я в этой теме плохо разбираюсь, был бы рад любым ресурсам)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Популярная статья на [Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/106912/).

Ветки создаются в зависимости от особенностей разработки и распространения ПО, а не от количества участников.

Главное, чтобы у вас был сетевой репозиторий, к которому в **обязательном** порядке все обращались. Также необходимо определиться кто имеет права коммитеть в ветку `master` и будут ли у вас `merge-request`.

Обычно из ветки `master` создаются релизы, тогда код в ней должен быть абсолютно рабочий. Если у вас есть тестировщики, то для них релизы могут создавать из ветки `pre-realese` и в случае успеха вливаться в `master`. Разработка в ветки `develop`.

Есть несколько варианта внесение нового функционала в код. Это объединять разработку нескольких новых функций под одну ветки или для каждой небольшой функции создавать *feature-branch*.

Comment: "Популярная статья на Хабре." --- ага, а ещё популярная: [Пожалуйста, перестаньте рекомендовать Git Flow](https://habr.com/ru/company/flant/blog/491320/)  + https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/05/02/git-workflows-that-work

Comment: просто большинство так называемых программистов (а по факту смузихлебов) так и не поняли, как это все работает и пытаются ввернуть свое видение. Мне посчастливилось работать в такой команде, где был официально git-flow, но на практике обложен таким кол-вом поправок, что ужас. Автор опуса о "перестаньте рекомендовать" - просто не смог осилить.